# How to scale image to 0.25 or resize image to 478*640 in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

In my application i **have image with** dimension **1936*2592** and size upto 6 MB.
i need **scale image to 0.25** or **resize image to 478*640** and then upload it to server.
I have tried lots of ways to do it in ios6 but failed

```
imageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.cl_PriviewImage);
UIImage *temp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: imageData];
ScaledImage = [temp resizedImage:CGSizeMake(478, 640) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
ScaledData = UIImagePNGRepresentation( ScaledImage);
```

//self.cl_PriviewImage is my image
it shows **resizedImage method not found**.
I have also tried with **ScaleToSize** method but its showing **same error**.

i have also tried with

```
ScaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.cl_PriviewImage.CGImage scale:0.25f orientation:self.cl_PriviewImage.imageOrientation];
ScaledData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ScaledImage);
```

in this case there is no error but my purpose didn't get fulfilled i.e uploaded image doesn't get changed in scale/size.

Is there any any other way in **iOS 6** or am i wrong some where?
Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*) image:(UIImage *) image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

You can also add this method in a `UIImage` category, that would be a better solution.

Comment: Hi is there any way that the image it returns should be with transparent background?..

Comment: I have tried with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 1); then it just covert background from white to black..

Comment: Or could it return image in PNG format? now it returns image in JPG format

Comment: @AjitSatarkar add `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`,  `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);` and `CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height));` before `[image drawInRect:]`.

Comment: @AjitSatarkar and `UIImage` has no "format" before you get a JPG or PNG representation from it.

Comment: Ok Thanks I'll definitely try this tomorrow in office. Well yesterday what i did was -

Comment: - (UIImage) image(UIImage ) image scaledToSize(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [image drawInRectCGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    ScaledData=UIImagePNGRepresentaion(newImage);
    ScaledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:ScaledData]
    return ScaledImage;
}

Comment: ScaledImage,ScaledData are objects of UIImage and NSData declared as Property in same classs. This works it returns image in PNG format which keeps my scaled image transparency as it is. Thanks